# how to fix this condition where while loop does not take 0 or value less than it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to calculate and the sentinel value of 0 or less in while loop 
Total length required lengthways = 6 m
Total length required widthways = 5 m

[image: Problem Statment]

the program is able to satisfy the condition of length and bread equals to 0 exists the loop but not negative numbers which are less than 0

and I am not able to calculate total length and make it a whole number.

```
length = float    
width = float    
sentinal = 0    
d1 = 1

d2 = 1
for i in range(20):

    while d1 != sentinal and d2 != sentinal:

        d1 = float(input("enter room dimension1 (m):"))

        d2 = float(input("enter room dimension2 (m):"))

        if d1 > d2:

                length = d1

                width = d2

                print("length = %.3f m" %(length))

                print("width = %.3f m" %(width))

        elif d2 > d1:

                length = d2

                width = d1

                print("length = %.3f m" %(length))

                print("width = %.3f m"%(width))
```

Comment: If this is a problem from a school assignment you might want to check this post and make sure your question follows these guidelines: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

please note: if this is a homework please don't copy the code blindly without understanding everything,  i will do my best to explain the code via # comments

```
import math  # required to use ceil() function , ex: ceil(3.2) = 4

def required_length(a, b):  # functions make your code organized
    length = max(a,b)
    width = min(a,b)
    print('length = ', length)
    print('width = ', width)
    print('Total length required lengthways = ', math.ceil(length))
    print('Total length required widthways = ', math.ceil(width))
    print()  # to look nice  print empty line for getting new input


while True:  # loop forever
    a = float(input('enter room dimension 1 (m): '))
    b = float(input('enter room dimension 2 (m): '))

    if a <= 0 or b <= 0:  # exit loop if user entered zero or minus
        print('invalid dimensions')
        break

    required_length(a, b)  # call our function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    sentinal = 0
    d1 = 1.0
    d2 = 1.0
    while d1 > sentinal and d2 > sentinal:

        d1 = float(input("enter room dimension1 (m):"))

        d2 = float(input("enter room dimension2 (m):"))

        if d1 > d2:

                length = d1

                width = d2

                print("length = %.3f m" %(length))

                print("width = %.3f m" %(width))
                print("Total length required lengthways: ", int(length)+1))
                print("Total length required widthways: ", int(width)+1))


        else:

                length = d2

                width = d1

                print("length = %.3f m" %(length))

                print("width = %.3f m"%(width))
                print("Total length required lengthways: ", int(length)+1))
                print("Total length required widthways: ", int(width)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

just wrote a optimise code

```
sentinal = True    
while sentinal:
        d1 = float(input("enter room dimension1 (m): "))
        d2 = float(input("enter room dimension2 (m): "))
        if 0 in (d1,d2) or 0.0 in (d1,d2):
            sentinal=False
        else:
            length, width = (d1,d2) if d1>d2 else  (d2,d1)
            print("leangth = %.3f m" %(length))
            print("width = %.3f m" %(width))
```